# How to send a string as file to the browser using php?

Tags: php, http-headers

I want to create a file in memory and send it to the browser when a button is clicked. I was expecting the following code to do the trick:

```
<?php

$content = 'This is supposed to be working... dammit';
$length = strlen($content);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testfile.txt');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');

echo $content;
exit;

?>
```

Instead I get the string echoed. What's my stupid newb error?

Comment: Turn on your PHP warnings. It's possible you've echoed something to the browser before your first `header()` here, in which case all your header statements will be ignored.

Comment: Why are you outputting a PDF?  I suppose it is entirely possible your browser is firing up your PDF reading plugin, it sees text, and is rendering it.

Comment: I tried all kinds of content type including octed-stream and pdf... Maybe it's something to do with my apache settings...

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm going through similar issues. The fact that the file extension is .txt when you're trying to download a pdf wouldn't be causing any issues would it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your content type, this works for me, tested on FF and Chrome

```
<?php 
$content = 'This is supposed to be working... dammit';
$length = strlen($content);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');//<<<<
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testfile.txt');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');

echo $content;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me using xampp on windows

Answer (score 1):

"Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent" ([c](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

Comment: If any output is sent before calling header() PHP will stop with an error. It will not output the string content.